# Efficient Logical AND of Every Combination of Two Mask Elements

Tags: python, numpy, combinations

I am looking to take a numpy array which is a 1D boolean mask of size N, and transform it into a new mask where each element represents a boolean AND over two mask elements (I don't want to repeat the same combinations twice since the order has no importance for the logical 'AND').

Example input:

```
mask = [1, 0, 1] = [a, b, c]
```

Expected output:

```
newmask = [1*0, 1*1, 0*1] = [0, 1, 0] = [a*b, a*c, b*c]
```

Comment: The masks are huge, I don't know how to numpy it. Using a for loop would take forever.

Comment: You're essentially trying to perform a logical and on the permutations of length 2, right?

Comment: Yes, with no repetitions. And I need to know what are the two elements in the input array that make up each result (index in the new array) -- mapping.

Comment: You said the arrays are big, how big are we talking? Also, what are you doing this for? Might there be a way around it?

Comment: The input array is ~500 in size. Its big personal data, I need to do about 10,000 of these operations, but I do have many cores and memory (they are saved as sparse). No way around. Majority of entries in output mask will be 0 / False.

Answer (score 0):

From a list of elements you can create all possibile combinations of them where their order doesn't matter, without wasting time on repeated combinations:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
import numpy as np

n = 3
elements_to_combine = [0, 1]
for c in combinations_with_replacement(elements_to_combine, n):
    x = np.array(list(c))
    print(x)
```

and the output is:

```
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1]
```

Now you have a straight foward method to compute only the combinations you need. You may also add elements to the list "elements_to_combine" and you may also increase the size of n according to your needs. Since you didn't specify precisely the kind of elmeents to be used and how you intend to mask your elements using the logical AND operations, I will leave the rest to you. Hope this solves your performance issues.

Cheers!